# zone of truth evasion and modify memory

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Are there any ways to evade a zone of truth, outside of clever wording? how would modify memory impact this? could you modify memory yourself to make what you believe what you are saying the truth?

Comment: Related, if not dupe: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147002/63061

Comment: I have closed this question because I believe it has been asked before. At the very least, it asks two different questions 1. Any methods of evading *zone of truth*, which has been asked about in [the marked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147002) and 2. How *modify memory* in particular works against *zone of truth*, which is mentioned in [an answer to that question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147006). If you remove the general case and want to solely ask about whether *modify memory* works (and also include why you think it might/might not work) that would be alright by me